# How do you use a non-alpha channel selection with basic paint tools?

Tags: gimp, layers, mask, selections, technique

Get your selection > Save to channel > Set channel as selection

How do you use things like pen, paintbrush, fill, exc. at this point?

When I go to use them they are in my edit history but I don't see it making changes to the picture.

Answer (score 1):

To use paint tools in the selection mask we may toggle to quickmask view (*Select > Toggle Quickmask* <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>):

Now when using paint tools they are shown in the red quickmask layer:

[image]

On toggling back to normal view we can see the usual selection dotted lines:

[image]

Comment: Make selection > Save Selection to channel > Select none > channel to selection > select > toggle on quick-mask > draw black line ( area goes red in the selection ) > toggle off quick-mask (everything disappears) ---- I want to spray paint only within the selection I saved but... It's proving rather difficult

Comment: Sorry, but I can't reproduce this here... all works as expected but after painting you may have to create a new selection mask in additon to the original.